# Power BI equivalent to SSRS groups

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a collection of invoices, some of which are for the same client.  I want to group by the client, and show the sums of YTD and Prior YTD, but also allow for the user to drill down in the individual client to see the individual invoice amounts.  This is possible in SSRS by creating a group.  Is this not possible in Power BI?

I have tried using the Group By in the edit query, but that seems to hide the original individual amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual#using-drill-down-with-the-matrix-visual) for that. For example, if you have a table like this:

[image]

Add `Client Name` and `Invoice Number` as rows, and `Amount` as value:

[image]

This way you will see the totals for the first "row" (127,00 for Client 1, etc.) and you can drill down to the next "row" (i.e. invoice numbers) and see individual rows. You can add multiple fields and get multiple drill downs. You can also add fields as columns, and get breakdown by something, e.g. invoice year.